# .NET 4.0 framework on same server as .NET 1.1

Tags: .net, iis-7, .net-4.0, .net-1.1

Can these framework versions work and play well on the same server?  Meaning that can IIS support two application pools where one pool is configured with .NET 4.0 and the other with .NET 1.1.

EDIT: This question is concerned with IIS 7.

Comment: I think this question belongs more on serverfault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0 CLRs all running in the same IIS instance, they are intentionally side-by-side installs to facilitate this, you'll have 3 options in the dropdown for your application pool .Net versions, one for each CLR version.

Answer (score 1):

yes - you can target the .net version of a specific framework in IIS [i use IIS 7] and can right click over an application pool > go to advanced settings and then choose .net framework version

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this via IIS or via command line:

```
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:  OldStuff /managedRuntimeVersion:v1.1  
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:  NewStuff /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0
```