# Upgrade to .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, webserver

my current version of .net framework on web server is 2.0 and now i want to run web apps of  .net framework 4.0 on same web server. before doing so i wants experts advice that if i will install .net framework 4.0 on my webserver then my webapplications of .net framework 2.0 will be affected or not and if yes then what should i do to handle both (2.0, 4.0) on my web server at same time.

Thanks

Comment: Check similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611399/net-4-0-framework-on-same-server-as-net-1-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing .Net 2.0 applications which are configured in IIS will not be affected by the install of .Net 4.0. You will have to manually change the application pool(s) to use .Net 4.0.